# Closest bounding function for lower minimal Goldbach p's peaks

Tags: number-theory

Mathematica Input:

Let:

GoldbachP[n_?EvenQ] /; n > 3 := 
 Block[{m = PrimePi[n/2], p}, 
  While[! PrimeQ[n - (p = Prime[m])], m--]; p]

valueset[n_] := 
 Module[{M}, 
  M = {k = n; 
    With[{kmin = Floor[k/4], kmax = Ceiling[k/2]}, 
     Table[k, {k, kmin, kmax}]]}; Flatten[M]]

interval[m_] := 
 StringJoin[{"[", ToString[First[valueset[m]]], ",", 
   ToString[Last[valueset[m]]], "]"}]

TableForm[Table[{i, GoldbachP[i], interval[i]}, {i, 4, 100, 2}], 
 TableDepth -> 2, TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "p", "[n/4, n/2]"}}]

plt1 = ListPlot[Table[n/4, {n, 4, 100, 2}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]

plt2 = ListPlot[Table[GoldbachP[n], {n, 4, 100, 2}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]

plt3 = ListPlot[Table[n/2, {n, 4, 100, 2}], Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Black]

Show[plt1, plt2, plt3]

Which function f[n] is the closest function bounding the lower (red) peaks of GoldbachP[n] (assuming that one exists at all)? For example; f[n]=n/4 (depicted in blue) is an attempt to find such a function.  Are there "better" functions than f[n]=n/4 out there?

Thank you!